# Do transactions are submitted as encrypted data to Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to know whether Hyperledger composer SDKs (Node JS) out of the box provides any encryption over transaction data.
Let's assume that if I am writing following transaction to the Hyperledger Fabric through a following composer terminal command,

```
composer transaction submit -c admin@tutorial-network -d '{"$class":"net.biz.digitalPropertyNetwork.RegisterPropertyForSale","transactionId":"TRANSACTION_001","seller":"mae@biznet.org","title":"TITLE_001"}'
```

or submitting trasaction through hyperledger composer SDK as in following code snippet (extracted from : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/reference/composer.transaction.submit.html)

```
const TransactionSubmit = require('composer-cli').Transaction.Submit;

let options = {
  card: 'admin@tutorial-network',
  data: '{"$class":"net.biz.digitalPropertyNetwork.RegisterPropertyForSale","transactionId":"TRANSACTION_001","seller":"mae@biznet.org","title":"TITLE_001"}'
};

TransactionSubmit.handler(options);
```

I can see that card value (admin@tutorial-network) is provided in both of above cases. And I can also understand that card contains necessary details to properly authorize access to the smart contract (in this case, RegisterPropertyForSale) too.

The problem is, when we send transactions to hyperledger fabric (fabric peers) for processing, do they send in an encrypted form and signed by the card? or are they just sent in plain text format?

Answer (score 2):

Fabric transactions are not encrypted; they are of course signed.
All of the SDKs sign the message using the private key associated with the client identity (including the identity cards used by Composer).

Encrypting the data in the transaction is left to the user.  Note that if you do encrypt the data, then every peer which will endorse the chaincode / smart contract must have access to the encryption/decryption key.  It's also possible to pass this in via the transient data field in the transaction message.  You'd need to do this directly via the SDK as this is not built-in to the Composer client.